# Correct word for pressing a button down without pressing up?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm making a game and I am doing the tutorial part of the game now. One of the buttons needs to be pressed down but should not be pressed up so that there is higher rewards. What is the correct word for "pressed down but should not be pressed up"?

I am thinking "hold down button"? Is that a correct word? Is that an internationally acceptable term?

Comment: Almost duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/534118/191178

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112152/discussion-on-question-by-jo-e-correct-word-for-pressing-a-button-down-without).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Press and hold". (There are plenty of Google hits for "press and hold the Control key" and the like.) And "release" for when you eventually take your finger off.

Comment: "Press and hold" sounds a lot better than what I was thinking! Thanks